# how to set in centos, it should open last open window after restart

Tags: linux, centos

I want to set that , if i shut down my system, and when i open it next time, then it should automatically open all window , that was opened before shut down as happen in windows.

my system is : centos :6.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PlateForm : **Centos 6.04**

Solution was :

1. Go TO **system menu** (Normally third button on top left)
2. You will Find **"Preference"** as a menu
3. select "**startup Application**" in prefrence
4. go to  **option** tab
5. select **remember Session** option.

It will work

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at [How to save a GNOME 3 session](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13725/how-to-save-a-gnome-3-session) assuming you're using GNOME. There is probably an equivalent version for KDE.

Comment: It Helped A little bit, but it does not solved my problem, yet i got how to solve.